# Best Practices: description vs debugDescription

Tags: swift, cocoa

Headline: description called by super.init()

This is a new take on an old question.  As a primarily Swift programmer I tend to not use NSObject for class definitions because of the residual side effects of Objective-C.  Like if I have a read-only property called *length* and I then want to create a setter function called *setLength*, I get warnings about it conflicting with a similar definition from Objective-C. I just discovered the *set(var){}* setter.  If I subclass a Cacoa class like UIDocument, etc. that inherit from NSObject, I have to live with these side effects.

I have a class that uses two other classes in the property definitions, none of them NSObjects.  This class has a *description* computed variable that uses the *description* computed variables for the other two classes in its composition.  All three classes need to conform to the CustomStringConvertable protocol.  Ok, everything is good.

At some point this class got upgraded to being a UIDocument and the CustomStringConvertable became redundant and was removed.  Everything still works.

Here is what I found out today. I wanted to break at a point in the program where it was printing one of the two properties and as a convenience I set the break point in the description variable for that class, thinking that it should only be called at the point I am interested in, where it is printed out. What I discovered is that the description variable gets called during all the super.init() of the UIDocument sub-class!  And there were a few of them.  I think composing strings as being relatively expensive but didn't care because they were only used in debug, but with them being called and who knows how they are used in super.init(), I need to change this.

I checked another UIDocument class in the same program that has 200 files associated with it and it is also calling description in super.init().

Does anyone have any input on the Best Practices for using *description* vs *debugDescription*?

I'm going to answer my own question as a matter of documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I switched the UIDocuments subclasses to define and use *debugDescription*. I am debugging some code that loads all the files and does some manipulation and I was able to reduce the load time from 9.8 seconds to 6.8 seconds.

I also went through all the places where the Swift 3 conversion added *String(describing:)* to the program and found I could change a lot of them to using *debugDescription* and eliminate the *String(describing:)* wrapper.

I think the best practice is to only define and use *debugDescription* and for my non-NSObjects change conformance from CustomStringConvertable to CustomDebugStringConvertable.